# Sending result from execute to onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

How can I pass result from **execute** method to **onActivityResult** for adding a calendar event which never directly returns to the app rather takes you to the calendar after adding the event.

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
```

which calls
`startActivityForResult(this, calIntent, RESULT_CODE_CREATE);`

**To**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
---->>How to access something generated as result from execute method here<<------
```

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult`, is invoked when the Activity started with `startActivityForResult` is finished. You can call the `setResult(int, Intent)` (before finish()) method to pass back your results.

Edit: example:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
   Intent data = new Intent();
   putExtra("key", "value");
   setResult(1000, data);
   finish();
}
```

when onActivityResult is invoked you will get your data in the `Intent` (the third parameter)

Comment: Which method should I call , can you be more descriptive